# build up and trade you

Tags: meaning

I'm translating a movie (Honeymoon) into Turkish, which is my native language. In this movie, a woman goes into a restaurant in her hometown and says: "I've been building up the maple beans here for years." What does she mean by that? Did she used to eat maple beans there or stock them?

Another example: A man is playing a dice game, I don't know what it is. And the woman  joins him saying "trade you." What does it mean? How can I translate that?

Thanks already for the one who is kind enough to reply my post.

Peace.

Answer (score 1):

"I've been building up the maple beans here" means "I've been **telling people how good** the maple beans here **are**", "I've been **promoting** the maple beans here"

Without more context I can't be certain, but "trade you" is probably just a shortened "I will trade/exchange (dice) with you".

Answer (score 1):

These are both idiosyncratic uses, hard to understand without more context.

The first, "I've been building up the maple beans" probably means that for some years, she has told others of her good opinion of the maple beans.  In a word, she *recommends* the maple beans.

In the second "trade you" could be an offer to trade seats, an offer to trade the position in the game, or an offer to give him something if he will give her the dice.  The meaning is *I offer to trade (some understood thing) with you.*